# Can someone tell me what I am doing wring

Tags: vb.net

The output I am getting is is not what I am suppose to be getting when you type in 50 dollars i should get 58 bars and 2 coupons but when i run it i am getting 57 with 7 coupons left. Thank you.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' declare variable
        Dim amountDollar As Integer
        Dim totalCoupons As Integer
        Dim leftOverCoupons As Integer
        Dim numberofChocolate As Integer
        Dim freeChocolate As Integer
        Dim totalchocolate As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your amount here")
        amountDollar = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        numberofChocolate = amountDollar
        freeChocolate = CInt(numberofChocolate / 7)
        totalchocolate = numberofChocolate + freeChocolate
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of chocolate: " & totalchocolate)
        leftOverCoupons = freeChocolate Mod numberofChocolate
        Console.WriteLine("Leftover Coupons: " & leftOverCoupons)
    End Sub

End Module
```

ok this is the new one but i can do it will the mod and the divison why is that

```
             Sub Main()
                ' This program will calculate the number of chocolate bars you can buy        or redeem by coupons for an input number
                   ' of dollars. Each bar costs one dollar and there is one coupon in each bar. It takes 7 coupons to receive one
                 ' additional chocolate bar.
             Dim dollars, numberOfBars, couponCount As Integer
              ' Prompt user to enter amount of money they have to spend
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy candy bars")
             Console.WriteLine("Yes")
             Console.WriteLine("No")
             Console.WriteLine("Please enter your amount here")
             dollars = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            ' Set value of numberOfBars and couponCount
               numberOfBars = dollars
    couponCount = numberOfBars
    ' Begin loop. Loop will determine total bars and remaining coupons
    Do While couponCount >= 7
        couponCount = couponCount - 7
        numberOfBars = numberOfBars + 1
        couponCount = couponCount + 1
    Loop

    ' Output values for ending number of chocolate bars and remaining coupons
    Console.WriteLine("The total number of chocolate bars you receive is: " & numberOfBars)
    Console.WriteLine("The number of coupons you have left is: " & couponCount)

End Sub
```

Okey I have figure it out just how do i stop the program if someone enters No?

Comment: You need to give more of your homework specification.  50 + (50 / 7) is certainly 57 when rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: well I am suppose to be able to get this output$20 gives 23 bar and 2 coupons left over or $50 would give you 58 bars and 2 coupons left over. I have been working on this all day.I am being ask to use integer division to determine the number of coupons redeemed then i will need to use the MOD to determine how many coupon i would have left.

Answer (score 0):

For the 58 compared to 57, I think 57 is actually what you are looking for - 50 bars plus (50/7) = 7.14 round down to 7 = 57

In the case where someone only buys 1 bar, you wouldn't want them to get a free bar, would you?

If you do want 58, then you need to use Double's for your maths and you need to use Math.Ceiling to get the next number up.

For the number of coupons left, I think you need to change:

```
leftOverCoupons = freeChocolate Mod numberofChocolate
```

to

```
leftOverCoupons = freeChocolate Mod 7
```

to improve the readability of your code a little, you should probably also define a local constant for this "magic number" of 7

Comment: ... and he should share some of that delicious chocolate. :-)